# VirtualHost custom log file not working in Apache web server

Tags: centos, logs, apache-httpd

I tried everything I know but httpd web server is still not writing on the custom log file. Strangely, its companion access.log which is in the same directory is fine. If I delete the error.log and sudo systemctl restart httpd, root becomes the owner of the file. The apache user is a member of the group.

Things I've done:

1. chcon --reference /var/log/httpd/error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
2. sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
3. sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/var/www/example.com/logs(/.*)?"
4. sudo restorecon -R -v /var/www/example.com/logs

> example.com.conf
> ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log

> ls -dlZ logs
> drwxrwxr-x. 2 user group unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 41 Jun 17 08:37 logs

> ls -lhZ error.log
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 user group system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 0 Jun 17 08:37 error.log

> ls -lhZ access.log
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 user group system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 318K Jul  9 06:51 access.log

> OS: Centos8
> Server: Apache
> VirtualHost: yes
> SELinux: enforcing

Comment: Quick question: are you putting your httpd logs in a directory that is published for content?  I.e., you can view the logs through the web interface?

Comment: The logs directory is in /var/www/example.com together with public_html.

Comment: You might be better off putting logs in /var/log/httpd/example.com/. Your logging issues might be because the directories leading up to the one you configured are locked down to prevent being used for logging.